# Why does my Android app freeze when using tag manager?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

A lot of the time the application won't launch because Tag Manager fails.
I get a lot of error stack traces when loading containers. 
Here are 3 that occur when Tag Manager forces the app to freeze before even starting:

1) PackageManager﹕ Package named 'com.company.myapp.dev.debug' doesn't exist.

2) InstalledAppDetails﹕ Exception when retrieving package:com.company.myapp.dev.debug

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
```

3) StrictMode﹕ StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=270 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=31 violation=2

```
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1137)
```

Is there any way to prevent this? Why does this occur?

I have TagManger segregated in a Singleton, here's the code to initialize:

```
public void init(final Activity context)
    {
        this.tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(context);
        tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
        PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pendingResult =
                tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(
                        context.getString(R.string.gtm_container_id),
                        R.raw.gtm_default_container);
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>()
        {
            @Override public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder)
            {
                setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
                containerHolder.getContainer();
                if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load container.");
                    //                        return;
                } else {
                    setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
                    containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
                }
                pushEnvironment();
                launchApp(context);
            }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

It's pretty much exactly the same as the CuteAnimals example.

Comment: I think the issue was attempting to use EasyTracker with Tag Manager. Though I can't really prove it. I wish I could read the source.

Comment: Please post the code where you initialize your tag manager instance

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem, app freeze when mDataLayer.pushEvent(event, map).
I do next check after pendingResult.setResultCallback(...);

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try { 
       AdvertisingIdClient.Info info = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
       if (info == null) mGtmAvailable = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mGtmAvailable = false;
    }
    if (mGtmAvailable) {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(App.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
            mGtmAvailable = false;
    }

}).start();
```

And then check mGtmAvailable  befor mDataLayer.pushEvent(event, map)